# URL Shorterners with an API like bit.ly, but without public stats?

Tags: php, api, url-rewriting

I'm wondering if there are any other URL shorterners with API's besides bit.ly. To remotely send long/return shortened urls.

I'm specifically looking for URL shorteners that don't make stats public (as bit.ly does).

(P.S. sorry if this is tagged wrong. I'll be using PHP to send/request data, so I thought I'd add it in as a tag).

Comment: Care to say why? I'm just looking to integrate a way to shorten urls en-masse in an application I'm creating, and using a public API for one of the big url shorteners seems like the most obvious way.

Comment: url shorteners are in my own (incredibly unbiased) book, a spammer cornerstone. And I use the stats page to view the full url to decide for myself if I want to even *think* about clicking the link. Removing the stats page imho is removing the only line of defense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[x.co](http://app.x.co/) will shorten URLs.  I'm not sure what you mean by "don't make stats public," so I don't know if this meets that requirement.

Comment: bit.ly allows public users to view stats (clicks) by appending the end of the url with a `"+"` is what I meant :), and thanks for the link.